# How to get data from api using jQuery's $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the data from the following(HTTP GET):
http://data.titantvguide.titantv.com/service.asmx?op=GetSchedules

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://data.titantvguide.titantv.com/service.asmx/GetSchedules?registrationKey=xxxxxxxxxx',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('testing');
        }

    });
});
```

Am I missing something? I don't see the console.log text.

Comment: What's the request status in `network` tab of `browser console`?

Comment: It says Status: 200

Comment: No other errors in your console? Nothing about *"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header..."*

Comment: Ah, I'm seeing that now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)